# Why is the "<from action" is not directing to the correct link using Django on the base.hml file

Tags: html, django, macos, nginx

Here is my base.html

```
      <div class="container">
    <div class="center">

         <form action='simple_test'> 
      <button id="simple_test" class="button-3d">  Generate</button>
         </form>
   </div>
     </div>
```

Here is my view.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse 
from django.shortcuts import render
from datetime import datetime
from django.template import loader
from django.core.files import File
from .unun import some_func
import random
import os

def index(request):
    strinput = {}
    glued, oldgued = some_func()
    strinput['IntPassHMTL'] = 433
    strinput['StrPassHMTL'] = glued
    strinput['BeforeGlued'] = oldgued

    return render(request,'index.html', strinput )


def simple_test(request):
    strinput = {}
    # glued, oldgued = some_func()
    strinput['IntPassHMTL'] = 433
    strinput['StrPassHMTL'] = "glued"
    strinput['BeforeGlued'] = "oldgued"
    print("Words?")
    return HttpResponse("This is a fake 404!")
```

Here is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    print("simple_test", views.simple_test),
    path('', views.index, name="index"),

]
```

misspelled pointed by @0svoid

```
    path("simple_test", views.simple_test),
    #print("simple_test", views.simple_test),
```

I tried to apply this solution to my codes and they still do not work right for my project. Not sure what I am missing.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `path` you have put `print`, so you haven't actually added the URL to your `urlpatterns` list! Try this:

```py
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path("simple_test/", views.simple_test),
        path('', views.index, name="index"),
    ]
```

The forward slash is only mandatory if you set `APPEND_SLASH = True` in your `settings.py` file.

Comment: damn you are very good at noticing...! anyway I tried that really with and without slash `path("simple_test/", views.simple_test)` & `path("simple_test", views.simple_test)` - but reall you are good!  I guess I was blind with `p` letter me and @shubham-sharma

Comment: Great! It’s easily done - accept the answer if it worked :)

Comment: sorry forgot to add " both kept giving me `404 Not Found` and  something not sure if related but chrome "Address Bar" showing `?` at the end of `.com/simple_test?` also at the end of my main site `www.domain.com/?`- but you are great!"

Comment: Guys, please give me more things I can try or different testing methods I can approach! @shubham-sharma

Answer (score 0):

Try adding / after your URL and in second URL you have print instead of path make these changes it should work.

'''

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path("simple_test/", views.simple_test),
        path('', views.index, name="index"),
    ]
```

'''

Comment: I wish that would fix it... Just tried it and still giving me `404 Not Found` I do not know what I am missing or what have done wrong in my project, I never was able to use any function besides `def index(request):`

Thank you for giving me things to try